# Natural cubic spline function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation, spline, cubic-spline, cubic

I am trying to write a MATLAB function which interpolates data points in X to create a natural cubic spline, similar to interp1 but without using interp1. The function takes inputs vector x and c (from the system Ac=Y) and vector X of data points that I want to interpolate.

My function is almost complete, I have put the system in matrix form, found the y values, coefficients a,b,c and d but I do not know how to evaluate the X values to get my estimated value Y.

For example, this is what I have at the moment:

```html
%cubic spline interpolation
n = length(x);
N = length(X);
Y = zeros(size(X));
for i = 1:n-1
    for j = 1:N
        while x(i) <= X(j) &&  x(i+1) >= X(j)
            Y(j) = a(i)*(X(j)^3) + b(i)*(X(j)^2) + c(i)*X(j) + d(i);
break
        end
    end
    
end
```

My question is why does this not work? I know interp1 does not find the natural spline but I am very new to MATLAB so I was just using this built-in function as a reference as to how the graph should look and my function is just completely wrong. I hope that makes some sense. Any help would be great.

Comment: What is the purpose of the "break" inside the while loop? It will stop the execution after one iteration of the loop.

Comment: Without the break, it becomes an infinite for-loop and doesn't work. It doesn't stop after one iteration I'm assuming because of the while loop, could you suggest a better way to write this? I know it's a bit shabby